# How to disable AutocompleteTextView Suggestion?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

```
if (cbIsGap.isChecked() == true) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please uncheck Is Gap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }else{
            try {
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select ConsAcNo From FieldUtilityData Where ConsAcNo like '%" + txtConsAcNo.getText() + "%' Limit 15 ", null);

                //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM FieldUtilityData  ",null);

                final String[] str = new String[c.getCount()];

                int i = 0;

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //assing values
                        String column2 = c.getString(0);
                        str[i] = c.getString(0);
                        i++;

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
                c.close();

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str);
                adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

                txtConsAcNo.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

Above is my code. **Now what i want that when check box is checked i dont want to show autocomplete suggetion**. But in my case its showing suggestion

Comment: Refer [How to disable AutoCompleteTextView's drop-down from showing up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495225/how-to-disable-autocompletetextviews-drop-down-from-showing-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the threshold value to 200-300

`myView.setThreshold(300);`

When you want to show the dropdown change it back to

`myView.setThreshold(1);` or `myView.setThreshold(2);` as you need.

This is not the exact way of doing it but a hack that would definitely work,

Comment: Thanks Srujan. Its work but when i uncheck CheckBox then my edittext focus not visible. can u solve this ?

Comment: @Moin Khan what do you mean? Elaborate please